# How to read all inputs from STDIN in Hackerrank?

Tags: python

I learned some of the basics of Python and wanted to try easy challenges in Hackerrank.

Input format:

- the first line contains integer
- the second line contains the space separated list of integers
- third line contains another integer.

In the coding part, it says

> Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

I am having difficulty reading and saving from STDIN. I want to save the first line integer as `X`, second line list as `list` and third line integer as `N`.

I don't understand how to do it. I have googled and tried to use some existing code, but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `input`:

```
# the first line contains integer
integer1 = int(input())

# the second line contains the space separated list of integers
int_lst = list(map(int, input().split()))

# third line contains another integer.
integer2 = int(input())
```

###### list of lists for 10 lines:

```
lst = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: thanks! what about the case when there are two space separated numbers in each line, and there are 10 such lines. How to save this data as 10x2 list?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use the input() to receive the input from STDIN and cast it to int as the input() function returns the STDIN as string.

To receive an integer:

```
>>> x = int(input().strip())
12
>>> x
12
```

To convert the list of space separated integers to list:

```
>>> y = list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))
1 2 3 4 556
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 556]
```

To create 2D list of integers:

```
>>> rows = 3
>>> array = []
>>> for i in range(rows):
...     each_line = list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))
...     array.append(each_line)
...
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
>>> array
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```